# Vue: How to bind checked value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, binding

For the last 10 hours straight i'm struggling with a seemingly simple issue, i hope someone can assist me.

Situation:

```
data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      has_items: [ 
      { "id": 19, "userId": 63, "projectId": 1, "project": { "id": 1, "titel": "Project1" } }, 
      { "id": 20, "userId": 63, "projectId": 2, "project": { "id": 2, "titel": "Project2" } } 
      ]
    },
    items: [
      { "label": "Project1", "titel": "Project1", "projectId": 1 },
      { "label": "Project2", "titel": "Project2", "projectId": 2 },
      { "label": "Project3", "titel": "Project3", "projectId": 3 }
    ]
  }
```

However, i can't seem to bind the `has_items` `projectId` to the checkbox checked state. I'm pretty confident it's one of those cases where messing around made things worse, and a simple solution is overlooked.

I've added an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebzgr4c3/31/

Hope someone can point out the error i made, and make this work :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what your desired outcome is, or what you mean by binding the `projectId` to the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes sure, the desired outcome would be that for every `items`, a checkbox is created based on the `user.has_items` values. Meaning, if `user.has_items` contains `projectId: 1`, the `items` with `projectId: 1` should be checked (and other way around of course). If there is no `user.has_items` value, it should be added when checking the checkbox

Comment: Why `user.has_items` objects `{ "id": 19, "userId": 63, "projectId": 1, "project": { "id": 1, "titel": "Project1" } }` have a different format than items `{ "label": "Project1", "titel": "Project1", "projectId": 1 }`, is this part of the requirement? or they must be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the elements in `user.has_items` have some extra formatting compared to the elements in `items`, I don't think `v-model` is really an option here. You'll need space to make some sort of translation from `item` to `has_item` happen between the time the checkbox is checked and the time the `project` is pushed onto the user's array.

You can make that space by trading v-model for a more manual option: events. In my example here, I used the `change` event to trigger a method that adds or removes the project, based on whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

I set the checkbox's initial value with another method. This method checks whether the checkbox's associated project is in the user's array of items.

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      has_items: [ 
      { "id": 19, "userId": 63, "projectId": 1, "project": { "id": 1, "titel": "Project1" } }, 
      { "id": 20, "userId": 63, "projectId": 2, "project": { "id": 2, "titel": "Project2" } } 
      ]
    },
    items: [
      { "label": "Project1", "titel": "Project1", "projectId": 1 },
      { "label": "Project2", "titel": "Project2", "projectId": 2 },
      { "label": "Project3", "titel": "Project3", "projectId": 3 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    userHasItem(project) {
      return this.user.has_items.find(e => e.projectId == project.projectId) != undefined;
    },
    updateHasItems(checked, project) {
      if (checked) {
        // Add item to user.has_items
        // [Translation between item and has_item goes here]
        this.user.has_items.push(project); 
      }
      else {
        // Remove item from user.has_items based on ID
        this.user.has_items.splice(this.user.has_items.findIndex(e => e.projectId == project.projectId), 1);
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div v-for="project in items" :key="project.projectId">
    <label>{{project.titel}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="userHasItem(project)" :value="project" @change="updateHasItems($event.target.checked, project)"/>
  </div>
  
  <p>User's items</p>
  {{user.has_items}}
</div>
```